# How to speed app launch time in react native

Tags: reactjs, performance

I am developing news app using react native, and my problem is the launch or startup time of app is slow (before the home screen shows), I would appreciate any advice to improve the speed.It takes around 3-4 seconds to load initially on my phone.

My package.json lokks like this :

```
{
  "name": "tageblattapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-optimized-flatlist": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^9.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.5",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.4.12",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.3.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.9.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "../assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

My imports are:

```
import React,{PureComponent} from 'react';
import {AsyncStorage, Linking ,Share, View ,Image,ActivityIndicator ,StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity,Dimensions,ScrollView,SafeAreaView, TextInput ,FlatList} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import {Container, Header, Left, Body, Right, Button, Title,Text,Content, List, ListItem,Thumbnail} from 'native-base';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { IMAGE } from '../constants/image';
import {  getMenusideGategory} from '../services/news';
import HTML from 'react-native-render-html';
import  Time  from '../components/time';
import moment from 'moment';
import  FeedDetail  from './FeedDetail';
import  ArticleLink  from './ArticleLink';
import  Comments  from './Comments';
import  AddComments  from './AddComments';
```

I have a warning message:

```
VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.
    in Context.Consumer (at VirtualizedList.js:1137)
    in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:633)
    in FlatList (at Home.js:244)
    in Feed (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
    in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
    in CardStack (created by KeyboardManager)
    in KeyboardManager (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Context.Consumer (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by Anonymous)
    in Anonymous (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by Drawer)
    in Drawer (created by DrawerView)
    in DrawerView (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (created by NavigationContainer)
    in NavigationContainer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> About the warning.

Yellow Warnings in react-native discloses inefficient code in your application which eventually leads to a performance issue or increase in memory consumption.

> Yes, the warning nesting VirtualizedList inside a plain ScrollView is bad for your app.

This usually happens while rendering Flatlist inside a ScrollView. (from your import)

- Flatlist fails to calculate the size of the current window and will try to render everything at the same time which leads to a performance problem.

> How to get rid of the warning

It's easy to resolve this issue just remove the `ScrollView` and move the components around `Flatlist` to `ListHeaderComponent` and `ListFooterComponent`

```
export default function WithWarning() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <ExampleComponent />
        <Text> Headlines </Text>
        <FlatList
          data={DATA}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          />
         <Text> Footer </Text>
      </ScrollView>
    );
 }
```

> Now lets get rid of the `ScrollView` and use props `ListFooterComponent` and `ListHeaderComponent`

```
export default function WithoutWarning() {
  return (
    <>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        LisHeaderComponent={(
          <>
            <ExampleComponent />
            <Text> Headlines </Text>
          </>
        )}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        ListFooterComponent={<Text> Footer </Text>}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

for more details and ways to optimize performance in a react-native app is available [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance)

Comment: Hello thank you for the answer, i remove the warning but still the performance is slow.